# Is there multiple files stored in the `stage` after `git add`?

Tags: git

As far as I know,after each operation of `git add "filename"`,the git will create an corresponding `object`,and restore a pointer to that `object` in the `index`.

Here is an example:

```
 touch a.txt 
 git add a.txt//version 1
 modify a.txt 
 git add a.txt//version 2
```

Are there two files stored in the `index`,which corresponds to version1 and version2?Or just exist the newest version2?

Will the version1 in `index` be deleted and only restore the version2?

Comment: it's just the newest version. If you want access to version1 of the file you need to commit that version. Tough you can commit the current content of stage *after* changing the file and *before* adding the current changes to stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation of `git add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) explains (emphasis is mine):

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> This command updates the index using the current content found in the working tree, to prepare the content staged for the next commit. ***It typically adds the current content of existing paths as a whole***, but with some options it can also be used to add content with only part of the changes made to the working tree files applied, or remove paths that do not exist in the working tree anymore.
>
> ***The "index" holds a snapshot of the content of the working tree***, and it is this snapshot that is taken as the contents of the next commit. Thus after making any changes to the working tree, and before running the commit command, you must use the add command to add any new or modified files to the index.

Without digging into implementation details, the staging area (aka the "index") keeps a copy of the current working tree. The files created, modified or deleted in the working tree can be "added" to the index using the [`git add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) and [`git rm`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm) commands.

This way the user prepares the content of the next commit. It is possible to commit only a part of the changes operated in the working tree and the index is used to store what will be committed next.

The index does not contain versions. It contains only one copy of each file, the one you added with the last `git add` command you ran.<sup>1</sup> If you modify the file after you add it to the index, the new changes won't be committed unless you add the file to the index again before committing it.

---

<sup>1</sup> The index is also updated by `git checkout`, `git reset`, `git merge` and other Git commands but they are not in the scope of this discussion.

Comment: There too many commands to let me remember the side effects of them.Is there a summary pamphlet which specifies the side effects(that is,whether it will update the index/working tree/repository)?

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question as asked is actually a bit tricky.  It's mostly *no*, but there are certain conditions—namely, conflicted merges—under which the index / staging-area *can* hold multiple versions for a single file.  Moreover, for some time, it's possible to retrieve any added version, but there's a hitch.

#### About the index / staging-area / cache

This thing called the *staging area* has three names, to reflect its importance and/or because it has multiple roles and/or because the first name for it, the *index*, is kind of a poor name. :-)  The three names are the *index*, the *staging area*, and the *cache*.

What the index does is to cache information (hence the *cache* name) about the work-tree.  As a result, it acts as an index for looking things up quickly about the work-tree (hence the *index* name).  The purpose of all of this is so that you can stage things for committing (hence the *staging area* name).

The main problem with all of this is that it is difficult to *see* the index and hence difficult to form a mental model about it.  Note that the work-tree can contain files that *aren't* in the index: these are, by definition, *untracked files*.  This means that listing the work-tree contents doesn't tell you what's in the index.

The main purpose of the index is to hold *whatever will go into the next commit*.  That is, `git commit` actually makes the new commit's content—the snapshot—*using* the index / staging-area.  Whatever is in the index now, *that* is what is in the new commit.

#### Viewing the index directly

To see what's in the index as a list of file names, use `git ls-files`.  To see this in more detail, use `--stage`:

```
$ git ls-files --stage
[snip]
100644 d76e13c8524003fcc5c55d706c1177f66520b9d4 0       builtin/checkout.c
100644 fad533a0a7382f10ecf48a738c955734ad5c0d96 0       builtin/clean.c
100644 101c27a593f4c64a735410f18bfcb46489728696 0       builtin/clone.c
[snip]
100755 067e9e7f4440a4a4a6f0dda6875fd3f840e694de 0       GIT-VERSION-GEN
100644 60e515eaf7432e77d8db8837b7bb95e105ca2126 0       INSTALL
100644 d38b1b92bdb2893eb4505667375563f2d6d4086b 0       LGPL-2.1
100644 a1d8775adb4b38a0340cd7d04184915f0ee65d28 0       Makefile
100644 f17af66a97c8097ab91f074478c4a5cb90425725 0       README.md
[snip]
```

This shows *how* the index holds a copy (a version, as it were) of each of the files in the work-tree.  The first entry gives the file's *mode*.  This is always<sup>1</sup> `100644` or `100755` for ordinary files: `100644` means it's not executable, while `100755` means it *is* executable.  The second, which looks a lot like a commit hash ID, is the *blob* hash ID of the staged content for that file.  The third number is called the *stage number:* it's usually zero, and I'll go into more detail in a moment.  After these three numbers, `git ls-files --stage` prints a tab character (ASCII code 9) followed by the file's full name, including any directory part and always using forward slash.

---

<sup>1</sup>In the distant past, Git stored more than just "executable" or "not executable".  That turned out to be a mistake, so now the only two normally-allowed values are the `100644` and `100755` numbers—but it also explains why the numbers have this many bits in them.  There are other file types, such as `120000` for a symbolic link.  The types mostly match the Linux/Unix inode bits.

---

#### The index version usually matches at least one of the HEAD or work-tree versions

You can see what's in your current *commit* using:

```
$ git ls-tree -r HEAD
[snip]
100644 blob d76e13c8524003fcc5c55d706c1177f66520b9d4    builtin/checkout.c
100644 blob fad533a0a7382f10ecf48a738c955734ad5c0d96    builtin/clean.c
100644 blob 101c27a593f4c64a735410f18bfcb46489728696    builtin/clone.c
[snip]
```

Compare this to the first section of `git ls-files --stage` output I retained above.  Except for the insertion of the word `blob` and the deletion of the stage number zero, these match exactly.

What's going on here is that when I checked out this commit from the Git repository for Git, Git extracted the files from the current commit:

```
$ git rev-parse master
0afbf6caa5b16dcfa3074982e5b48e27d452dbbb
```

into the index and work-tree.  In the index, they're just stored as blob hashes—the *same* hash as the commit itself, and in fact, they're sharing the internal Git *blob* object holding the file's content.  We can view the content directly using the hash IDs; for instance, `README.md` has hash ID `f17af66a97c8097ab91f074478c4a5cb90425725`, so:

```
$ git cat-file -p f17af66a97c8097ab91f074478c4a5cb90425725
Git - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system
=========================================================

Git is a fast, scalable, distributed revision control system with an
unusually rich command set that provides both high-level operations
and full access to internals.
[snip]
```

Note that these *blob* objects, stored by their hash ID in the Git repository object database, are in a special, read-only, Git-specific form.  That's one reason we have to use `git cat-file` to read them, rather than just looking at `.git/objects/...`.  Another reason is that they can get *packed* and then there's no individual object to examine.

#### Running `git add` creates or re-uses a blob

When you run `git add path`, Git copies the work-tree version—which is in its ordinary form and is generally read/write, so that you can change it—into the internal form, as a blob object.  If the file's content exactly matches some existing blob object, Git will just re-use that existing blob object.  Otherwise, Git will create a new read-only blob object to hold that content.

In any case, the result of this *re-use existing or create new* process is that there is now a blob object in the repository's object database, and this blob object has a hash ID.  Git can now stuff the new hash ID into the index.  For instance, if I modify the `README.md` file:<sup>2</sup>

```
$ ed README.md 
3001
1i
hello world
.
w
3013
q
$ head -3 README.md
hello world
Git - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system
=========================================================
```

and then `git add` this, I get a new entry in the index:

```
$ git add README.md
$ git ls-files --stage -- README.md
100644 331117c13c79da78d15ad24c2111c15eeef56ddf 0       README.md
```

and the blob hash matches that from `git hash-object`:

```
$ git hash-object README.md 
331117c13c79da78d15ad24c2111c15eeef56ddf
```

and now I have a different version of `README.md` in the index.

If I change `README.md` again and add it again, the staged hash ID will change.  Let's change the added line, predict the hash, add the file, and see:

```
$ head -3 README.md
jello world
Git - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system
=========================================================
$ git hash-object README.md
2be1367cce5788ee15d4de758fc95599721dd1f4
$ git add README.md
$ git ls-files --stage -- README.md
100644 2be1367cce5788ee15d4de758fc95599721dd1f4 0       README.md
```

What happened to the intermediate one we added?  Well, at least for the moment, it still exists:

```
$ git cat-file -p 331117c13c79da78d15ad24c2111c15eeef56ddf | head -3
hello world
Git - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system
=========================================================
```

(In fact, due to the rules for pruning unreferenced objects, it will stick around for 14 days by default.)

If I want the `README.md` file to go back to the version in the `HEAD` commit, I can use `git checkout` to extract that into the index, and then on into the work-tree:

```
$ git checkout HEAD -- README.md
$ git ls-files --stage -- README.md
100644 f17af66a97c8097ab91f074478c4a5cb90425725 0       README.md
```

Note that it's possible, but unusual, to `git add` a file, then change it some more.  When you `git add`-ed it, you get a snapshot of what was in the work-tree at the time; when you changed it more, you made another version; and now the index version may differ from *both* the `HEAD` version *and* the work-tree version.

Using `git add -p` does this same sort of thing: after applying each diff hunk, it `git add`s the patched version that it's building up.  As a result, you can get many objects that must be cleaned-up 14 days later.  For instance, if you have 14 diff hunks and add 13 of them, you get 12 intermediate versions in the object database, plus the 13th that you actually commit.  This is normal and pretty harmless unless you are using `git add -p` on a twelve terabyte file. :-)

---

<sup>2</sup>I use the `ed` editor here since it's reproducible in plain text.  The first number, `3001`, is the file's initial size in bytes.  The `1i` command inserts text before line 1, and `.` on a line by itself ends the insertion.  The `w` command writes the file, which reports the size in bytes, and `q` exits the editor.  You can see that I added twelve bytes: "hello" and "world" are 5 each, the space is one, and the final newline is the twelfth.

---

#### Viewing the index indirectly

When you run `git status`, you will often see *changes staged for commit* and *changes not staged for commit*.  What is really going on here is that Git is running two comparisons—two `git diff`s, more or less.  One compares the current or `HEAD` commit to the index.  Whatever is *different* here is *staged for commit*.  Whatever is the same here, it says nothing about.

**But** then it goes on to compare the index contents to the work-tree contents.  Whatever is different *here* is *not* staged for commit.  Whatever is the same here, it says nothing about.

**Viewing the index *indirectly* like this is generally more useful** than viewing it directly.  We mostly want to know: *What, in the next commit I am about to make, is already changed from the current commit?*  In other words, what's the difference between `HEAD` and the index?  And: *What else could I `git add` to make the index more different?*  In other words, what's the difference between the index and the work-tree?

Since these are the most useful to know, these are what `git status` shows.

#### Nonzero stage numbers: how Git merges files

All this tricky stuff with the staging area is somewhat useful, especially for `git add -p`, but in the end you could easily get away without it.  Mercurial, which is very similar to Git in many ways, has no staging area—you just run `hg commit` and it commits whatever is in the work-tree.<sup>3</sup>  The work-tree *is* your staging-area: you just edit and go.<sup>4</sup>

During `git merge`, though—or actually anything that invokes Git's *merge machinery*, the part of merge that I like to refer to as *merge as a verb*—the index takes on a much bigger role, and it's here that the stage numbers actually matter.

To do any ordinary [three-way merge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(version_control)#Three-way_merge), Git needs *three* inputs: a merge base commit, the current (`HEAD`) commit, and the commit you wish to merge.  Each commit typically has one version of each file.  Git can now write, into the index / staging-area, *all three versions*, using the stage number that's ordinarily just zero:

```
$ git merge br1
Auto-merging file
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
$ cat file
base file
<<<<<<< HEAD
different stuff
||||||| merged common ancestors
=======
new stuff
>>>>>>> br1
$ git ls-files --stage
100644 56a073d1bdc0307f357a407b50bee4324bb55873 0       README
100644 4bbeee7f6db44d17c38abd3031fcb84a97192459 1       file
100644 66c11225b90f34558b8ace8c5eb203ec47b55c38 2       file
100644 7502e0fdd9ef370b5eee377ceeee4b1605d88336 3       file
```

(I have `merge.conflictStyle` set to `diff3`, so I see all three versions in the work-tree file named `file` here.)

Note that the index now has *three* entries for file `file`.  The stage-1 entry, with hash ID `4bbeee...`, is the *merge base* version.  The stage-2 entry, hash ID `66c11...`, is the `HEAD` or `--ours` version.  The stage-3 entry, `7502e...`, is the version from the branch `br1`.

The `README` is the same in every version—all three hashes matched—so Git was able to leave it alone, and it's at stage zero.

During the merge operation—which happens only if *all three versions differ*—if Git is able to combine the three versions on its own, it will do so and put the merge result in as stage zero.  If not—if there are any merge conflicts—Git will leave all three versions in as the three stages, and write its best guess at the merge, plus the conflicts, into the work-tree.

The thing that makes this so easy if two or three of the hash IDs match is that we then just have the following cases:

- All three hash IDs match: *we* didn't touch the file and *they* didn't touch the file, so keep the base / ours / theirs version of the file.  They are all the same!
- Two of the three IDs match.  Then one of the following must be true:

  - The base version matches ours: only they changed it; take *their* file.
  - The base version matches theirs: only we changed it; take *our* file.
  - The base version is different, but ours matches theirs: take ours or theirs, whichever is easier, since we both made *the same* changes.

Hence Git only has to run the full three-way merge algorithm on files where all three versions differ.  Even then, as I noted above, Git *may* be able to resolve the merge on its own.  It's only if it *can't* that it puts all three versions into the index and stops with a merge conflict.

Once Git *has* stopped with a merge conflict, note that `git add` takes whatever's in the work-tree, writes it into a blob object, then writes the ID into slot zero and *removes* the three higher-stage entries.  That's what marks the conflict as resolved.

---

<sup>3</sup>This isn't quite true: for *new* files, you must `hg add` the file.  The principle should be clear enough, though.  Mercurial has a secret place it keeps much of what's in Git's index, which Mercurial calls its *dirstate*, but you do not have to know about it.  The dirstate does not hold multiple versions the way Git's index does, though.

<sup>4</sup>If you use `git commit -a`, Git effectively—but not actually; there's special sneakiness under the hood—runs a `git add -u` to update the index just before doing the commit.  This makes Git act a lot like Mercurial: you only have to `git add` *new* files.  There's some asymmetry here with *removed* files, though.  Mercurial used to remove them automatically, just as `git add -u` will, but that turned out to be a mistake.  I recommend *not* using `git commit -a` as it will probably bite you eventually.

---

#### Summary

This is what you should know about the index / staging area / cache:

- It has three names.  They all mean the same thing; they just emphasize different roles, or were typed in by different people.
- It's the place you build up the next commit to make.  Running `git commit` will use whatever is in the index *right then* to make the commit (ignoring special weirdness from `git commit -a` or `git commit --only <file>` or `git commit --include <file>`).
- It generally starts out matching the current commit (but it doesn't *have* to: see also [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452)).
- Running `git add` copies files *from* the work-tree, *to* the index.  All commits, including the current commit, are read-only, so there's nothing to overwrite a commit: that's completely impossible.

  The files get stored into the object database, so in case of disaster, you can use `git fsck --lost-found` to find what Git calls *unreachable* blob objects.  These will have the contents you `git add`ed, but the file *names* will be lost.
- Other commands (not covered much or at all above) copy files *from* the index *to* the work-tree, or from commits, *through* the index, to the work-tree.  The main command for this is `git reset`.

  It's somewhat difficult to copy a file out of a commit without first writing it into the index.  Thus, the commands that copy from commits—including `git reset`—first overwrite the index version.
- Conflicted merges use higher-stage number index slots.  Thus, merging occurs via the index, too.  Except for merging itself, writing into the index collapses away these higher-stage versions, leaving only the normal slot-zero entry.

There are, of course, maintenance / plumbing commands that can set up higher stage index entries, and tools for fussing with the index.  We saw `git ls-files` above for viewing it, and `git update-index` can change it.  But you don't need either of these in everyday Git usage.

Answer (score 3):

Only the latest version added will be accessible from the index.

You can use `git ls-files --stage` to inspect what files are currently in the index.

What happens when you `git add` something is that a new `blob` object will be created. This object is then referenced from the index. So if you add a change, then find the blob hash for the resulting file (by for instance `git ls-files --stage`) and keep ahold of this blob hash, then you will be able to find it even if the index is updated to record a different blob for the given file, until it eventually gets garbage collected.

An example:

Create file `foo` with contents `hello blob` and add it to the index.

```
$ echo "hello blob" > foo && git add foo
```

Find the blob reference from the index and show the blob contents.

```
$ git ls-files --stage | grep foo
100644 038f48ad0beaffbea71d186a05084b79e3870cbf 0   foo
$ git cat-file -p 038f48ad0beaffbea71d186a05084b79e3870cbf
hello blob
```

Replace the contents of `foo` with `good bye blob` and add it to the index.

```
$ echo "good bye blob" > foo && git add foo
```

Find the blob reference from the index and show the blob contents.

```
$ git ls-files --stage | grep foo
100644 d026852604f5986457e8867e2cb27b4cddb24e6f 0   foo
$ git cat-file -p d026852604f5986457e8867e2cb27b4cddb24e6f
good bye blob
```

The original blob still exists until it gets garbage collected.

```
$ git cat-file -p 038f48ad0beaffbea71d186a05084b79e3870cbf
hello blob
```

[Documentation/technical/index-format.txt](https://github.com/git/git/blob/90bbd502d54f/Documentation/technical/index-format.txt) gives more information about the internal format of the index.

Comment: So git will diffentiate files according to their filename when we use `git add`,and leaves only the newest version?

Comment: I added some more information to the answer that I hope helps clarify.